# Nested Loops and If statements

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, dummy-variable

So the code I have below attempts to find WIP in column H. If we find WIP: copy 3 cells and make 10 replicas of them in the next column either in the same row or the next available row.

For some reason the code only runs the loop successfully for the first "WIP" value and then stops running. Can someone see why this keeps happening?

Thank you, 
Ori

Sub Step1_update()

```
Dim dblSKU As Double
Dim strDesc As String
Dim strType As String
Dim BrowFin As Integer
Dim Browfin1 As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Trowfin As Integer

Counter = 0

Worksheets("Final").Activate

Trowfin = 5
BrowFin = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'loop 1
    Do While Trowfin < BrowFin

        'If 1
        If Range("H" & Trowfin).Value = Range("H3").Value Then

             dblSKU = Range("F" & Trowfin).Value
             strDesc = Range("G" & Trowfin).Value
             strType = Range("H" & Trowfin).Value

             Browfin1 = (ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

             'If 2
             If Browfin1 > Trowfin Then

                Do While Counter < 15

                    Range("J" & Browfin1).Value = dblSKU
                    Range("K" & Browfin1).Value = strDesc
                    Range("L" & Browfin1).Value = strType

                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    Browfin1 = Browfin1 - 1
                    Trowfin = Trowfin + 1

                Loop

              ElseIf Browfin1 < Trowfin Then

                 Do While Counter < 15

                    Range("J" & Trowfin).Value = dblSKU
                    Range("K" & Trowfin).Value = strDesc
                    Range("L" & Trowfin).Value = strType

                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    Trowfin = Trowfin + 1

                 Loop

                Else

                 Do While Counter < 15

                    Range("J" & Trowfin).Value = dblSKU
                    Range("K" & Trowfin).Value = strDesc
                    Range("L" & Trowfin).Value = strType

                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    Trowfin = Trowfin + 1

                 Loop
                'If 2
                End If


        Else

            Trowfin = Trowfin + 1

        'If 1
        End If

    counter = 0 

    'loop 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reset your counter back to 0 after you loop through it.  Otherwise you are already at the 15 the next time you get to the loop again.

Comment: For some reason if the "WIP" shows up below another "WIP" only the first one is copied, any idea why?